# Google cloud function (python) does not deploy - Function failed on loading user code

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm calling a simple python function in google cloud but cannot get it to save. It shows this error:

"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."

Logs don't seem to show much that would indicate error in the code. I followed this guide: https://blog.thereportapi.com/automate-a-daily-etl-of-currency-rates-into-bigquery/

With the only difference environment variables and the endpoint I'm using.

Code is below, which is just a get request followed by a push of data into a table.

```
import requests
import json
import time;
import os;

from google.cloud import bigquery

# Set any default values for these variables if they are not found from Environment variables


PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("PROJECT_ID", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
EXCHANGERATESAPI_KEY = os.environ.get("EXCHANGERATESAPI_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
REGIONAL_ENDPOINT = os.environ.get("REGIONAL_ENDPOINT", "europe-west1")
DATASET_ID = os.environ.get("DATASET_ID", "currency_rates")
TABLE_NAME = os.environ.get("TABLE_NAME", "currency_rates")
BASE_CURRENCY = os.environ.get("BASE_CURRENCY", "SEK")
SYMBOLS = os.environ.get("SYMBOLS", "NOK,EUR,USD,GBP")

def hello_world(request):
    
    latest_response = get_latest_currency_rates();
    write_to_bq(latest_response)
    return "Success"

def get_latest_currency_rates():
    PARAMS={'access_key': EXCHANGERATESAPI_KEY , 'symbols': SYMBOLS, 'base': BASE_CURRENCY}
    response = requests.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest", params=PARAMS)
    print(response.json())
    return response.json()

def write_to_bq(response):

    # Instantiates a client
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT_ID)

    # Prepares a reference to the dataset
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(DATASET_ID)

    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(TABLE_NAME)
    table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref) 

    # get the current timestamp so we know how fresh the data is
    timestamp = time.time()


    jsondump = json.dumps(response) #Returns a string


    # Ensure the Response is a String not JSON
    rows_to_insert = [{"timestamp":timestamp,"data":jsondump}]

    errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # API request
    print(errors)
    assert errors == []
```

I tried just the part that does the get request with an offline editor and I can confirm a response works fine. I suspect it might have to do something with permissions or the way the script tries to access the database.

Comment: Did you include a requirements.txt file that lists the google cloud library? Well, and the other required libraries that aren't standard.

Comment: google-cloud-bigquery==2.13.0 and
Flask==1.0.2 are the ones in my requirements.txt

I was following the guide from https://blog.thereportapi.com/automate-a-daily-etl-of-currency-rates-into-bigquery/

Comment: requests isn't in the core Python either, you'll need to add it there too: 
 `requests==2.25.1`. That might be it?